# Why my trigger is not working with Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a Java spring boot project and I use Hibernate in this project. I have a `void deleteAll(List<Long> idList)` method and its query is `@Query(value = "DELETE c FROM Course c WHERE c.id in :idList", nativeQuery = true)`. I want to use a trigger after every delete operation. I created a trigger in mysql and it works when I try in mysql, but it doesn't work when I call `void deleteAll(List<Long> idList)` method. How can use my trigger with hibernate?

My trigger defination:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_delete_course AFTER DELETE ON course FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE tc1 FROM table1_course tc1 WHERE tc1.course_id = OLD.id;
    DELETE tc2 FROM table2_course tc2 WHERE tc2.course_id = OLD.id;
    DELETE tc3 FROM table3_course tc3 WHERE tc3.course_id = OLD.id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

SQL generated by hibernate when deleteAll is called :

```
Hibernate: 
    DELETE c 
    FROM
        Course c 
    WHERE
        c.id in (
            ?
        )
```

Comment: Please show your trigger definition.

Comment: maybe `deleteAll(List<Long> idList)` does not commit the transaction? Are the rows in `course ` deleted after the method call?

Comment: The method works, but it deletes only courses not table1_course, table1_course  and table1_course.  @fantaghirocco

Comment: Show SQL generated by hibernate when deleteAll is called

Comment: I edited question @A.Alexander

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you know it doesn't work? You won't see the delete queries of your trigger being logged in your application, this is happening only on the DBMS side.
If you have an `EntityManager` that contains the deleted entity or the associations deleted by the trigger, you will have to detach them from the `EntityManager` to get a consistent view again, as Hibernate does not know what effects DML statements will have on the managed entities. Try using `EntityManager.clear` after executing this DML statement.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use the entity lifecycle annotations provided by JPA.

In this case, you are performing a delete operation. So, you can use the `@PreRemove` annotation.

You can check some examples [on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events)